# How to read values from a file(.TXT or .conf) in another .conf file

Tags: python, shell, config

Say I have 2 config files : global.conf & specific.conf . Is it possible to import values from global.conf to specific.conf(I have 10 files) file in Unix ?

Global.conf:::

`Value1= alpha`

Specific.conf:::

```
[General]
value2 = $value1
[Default]
Value3 = xxx
```

Edit::
I did try including global.conf by using `source` or `.` yet it was not working (I doubt if it's the right way to do it)

```
. /Path/to/global.conf

[General]
value2 = "$value1"
[Default]
Value3 = xxx
```

I want to do this because I have few variable parameters(such as hostname)in global file which might be updated in future, so I was thinking if I could just change the value in one place then it would be reflected in all the specific files. And I am trying to read the values from this specific.conf file in a python program

Any suggestions on how to achieve this via python/shell would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: When you write code to read these files, you can add whatever features you want, yes...

Comment: It’s in the standard library all ready for you... https://pymotw.com/3/configparser/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I have already gone through the configparser but I don't think this will help me here. Since I would like to read the value from global file & call it in the specific file & each time I change the value in global it must change in specific too. So it is basically like importing the global the file in the specific file. Is there any way to do this?